# How to code VBA to paste values or formulas based on font color?

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, colors

Still new to VBA and need help modifying some existing code.

Several IF statements need to occur in the new code: If copied font is green, paste as values and change font color from green to blue. If copied font is anything other than green, paste as formulas.

```
Sub InvestorModelMacro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
DisplayGridlines = False

Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet

For Each r In Worksheets("Asset Dashboard").Range("C6:C9")   'go through each cell in DV list
    If Len(r) > 0 Then                                       'only do something if cell not empty
       Worksheets("Live").Range("D3").Value = r.Value        'transfer value to cell D3 of 'Live' tab
       Application.Calculate
       Set ws = Worksheets.Add                               'add new sheet
       ws.Name = Worksheets("Investor Model").Range("D3")    'renames new sheet after selected asset
       Worksheets("Investor Model").Cells.Copy
       ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues                   'copy values only from Investor Model to new sheet
       ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats                 'copy formats only from Investor Model to new sheet
       ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False                 'turns off gridlines

End If
Next r

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the code below is still returning formulas for all cells pasted into new worksheets. I need the green font to be pasted as values, and all other font colors to remain as formulas...

```html
Sub InvestorModelMacro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
DisplayGridlines = False

Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet

For Each r In Worksheets("Asset Dashboard").Range("C6:C9")   'go through each cell in DV list
    If Len(r) > 0 Then                                       'only do something if cell not empty
       Worksheets("Live").Range("D3").Value = r.Value        'transfer value to cell D3 of 'Live' tab
       Application.Calculate
       Set ws = Worksheets.Add                               'add new sheet
       ws.Name = Worksheets("Investor Model").Range("D3")    'renames new sheet after selected asset
    If r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 153, 0) Then
        r.Copy
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 153, 0)
    Else
        r.Copy
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End If
       Worksheets("Investor Model").Cells.Copy
       ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormulas                'copy values only from Investor Model to new sheet
       ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats                 'copy formats only from Investor Model to new sheet
       ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False                 'turns off gridlines

End If
Next r

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with colors you want to access the `Font.ColorIndex` property.

You will need to figure out what Color Index # relates to whatever shade of Green is being used on your sheet as well as whatever shade of Blue you want to use and sub them in the code below

---

Pseudo code:

```
For Each R in xRange
    If Len(R) > 0 Then
        If R.Font.Color = [Green Font Index #] Then
            R.Copy
            Range("?").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Range("?").Font.Color = [Blue Font Index #]
        Else
            R.Copy
            Range("?").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            Range("?").Font.Color = [What color do you want here?]
        End If
    End If
Next R
```

---

*I would personally prefer to not use colors as the logic driver here. If there is some logic that exists on the sheet that determines what colors the cells fonts are pre-macro **(something like conditional formatting)**, you may be better off recreating that logic here*

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be difficult for me to add conditional formatting to the entire worksheet... this is crunch time for me. Thank you for the pseudo code. I am looking over the Font.ColorIndex numbers and it appears that Color 1 and Color 2 represent Black and White, respectively. Would it be possible to say any color greater than 2 needs to be pasted as a value? And anything less than 2 pasted as a formula?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. The question is WHY is the cell green in the first place? If there is a reason that you can recreate in excel, you may be able to just recreate that logic in VBA. May be more intuitive than working with colors

Comment: I see - the logic behind why cannot be replicated with conditional formatting. We manually changed the font colors to denote which need to be saved as values - we will be sharing this file with a third party and do not want them viewing our methods/formulas...

Comment: Should probably be `Font.Color`, not `.ColorIndex`. The latter is just an index into the current color palette.

Comment: @bigben could you please show me how this might look within my existing code?

Comment: @MEDITATED - this code shows you how it would look within your existing code. If you are looking for someone to completely write out your code for you, you have come to the wrong site

Comment: Mr. Boy, check the edit I made to my post, the code is already written, just new to vba and not sure how to incorporate it correctly